# Need a combination of geoprocessing tools that could replace Extract By Mask for use with WPF Runtime

Tags: arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing-package, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I am in need of a combination of geoprocessing tools that could replace Extract By Mask for use with WPF Runtime.  The "Extract by Mask" tool is one of the tools that is not supported with Runtime.  Also "Reclassify" is one tool that is not being supported by Spatial Analyst extension.

However, right now I just want to concentrate on the Extract By Mask.  When I use that tool in my model, run the model and then try to create a geoprocessing package (gpk) from that result, I get an error message letting me know that that tool is not supported.  Therefore I need a combination of tools that could be used in my model, that would accomplish the same goal.

Thanks,
Renee

Comment: What format of rasters are you using?

Comment: @Kirk, Rasters are DTED1 and DTED2.

Comment: One answer that I got was that I can try to use “Data Management tools”-> ”Rasters”-> ”Raster Processing”-> ”Clip Tool” as a substitute for Extract by Mask.